# SQL index with in clause

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle10g, in-clause

Our application has suddenly gone slow in one of the env. The only change I have done is changed the SQL. Before release, the SQL was something like this

```
Select EmployeeId 
From Employee 
Where Dept='CS' 
  and record_state='ACTIVE' 
  and EmployeeTypeId ='1'
```

After release SQL is

```
Select EmployeeId 
From Employee Where Dept='CS' 
 and record_state='ACTIVE' 
 and EmployeeTypeId IN ('1','2')
```

The index on this table is employee_state_id_index (Dept,record_state,EmployeeTypeId ) 
The index has not been changed. Does this index not help the new SQL? does the new SQL scan the whole table? I have no idea how indexes work with in clause. Appreciate your help and comments

The explain plan for the query is

```
| Id  | Operation         | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|

|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT  |                          |     1 |    57 |     4   (0)|
|   1 |  DELETE           | Employee                 |       |       |            |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| employee_state_id_index  |     1 |    57 |     4   (0)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT


   2 - access("C"."Dept"='CS' AND
              "C"."RECORD_STATE"='ACTIVE')
       filter("C"."EmployeeTypeId"='1' OR
              "C"."EmployeeTypeId"='2')
```

Comment: Check the execution plan. It will tell you exactly if the index is used. You should also tell us which DBMS you are using. Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Did you check the explain plan? Can you post that for us here?

Comment: The execution plan is for a `DELETE` statement, yet your question shows a `SELECT` statement. So apparently there is something you are not telling us

Comment: your passing in `EmployeeTypeId` as a `number` in the first instance, and a character in the second. this can change the plan (The plan shows that `EmployeeTypeId` is a `varchar2` as Oracle kept the quotes there). secondly, are you sure the index is exactly as you described? as the plan shows FILTER on the `EmployeeTypeId` and not ACCESS. I'd usually expect this if another column was in the index prior to the `EmployeeTypeId` column (i.e. the index isn't ideal). also the `rows` in the plan shows 1 row estimated for that query. if this is off by magnitudes then this will also hinder things.

Comment: How many records have EmployeeTypeID = 2 in relation to those that are = 1? If many rows have the value 2, the optimizer will likely not use the index and table scan instead. Try your original SQL for EmployeeTypeID = 2 only. If that takes a long time, then the performance issue is a function of your data rather than your query.

Comment: Sorry @a_horse_with_no_name. I was trying a lot of statements here, I tried with delete and than select. While pasting the above, I made a mistake of getting the wrong plan output here. Sorry for that

Comment: Please post the execution plan for both versions of the statement.

Comment: Thanks @DazzaL thanks a lot for the explanation. I think I have started understanding this better. Yes the index to the table is as mentioned above. I have no idea what is access and filter used for. I think I need to read thro' the docs to understand it better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I ultimately took a help of a DBA and reindexed the tables. The table had huge amount of data (some redundant, was a bug in the system, which was fixed eventually). So we deleted the redundant data and had not reindexed the table. Reindexing fixed the whole lot of issues. Thanks a lot for all the help and suggestions given. It did help me analyse the issue

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer and accept it? This will help anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem we faced, was reindexing the table. The table had a 10 million records and we recently cleaned up the data in the table (when we realized that we had duplicate records) and that reduced it to almost half of the amount of records it previously had. So we thought we will give a try with reindexing, since anyway it needed it. And that helped :)